# Controller functions not being called from ng-click link in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, click

I'm using the Angular Bootstrap Calendar with a [custom cell template](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=custom-templates) and [cell modifier](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=cell-modifier). In my controller, I"m building a bunch of tables inside each day cell. Some of the cells have a link that, when clicked on, should run a function in my controller to add or delete a record on the back end and change the content of the cell.

Here's the ui-router definition:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    })
    .state ('calendar', {
      url : '/calendar',
      templateUrl: 'views/calendar/index.html',
      controller: 'calendarController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
```

Here's the relevant controller code:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('formioAppBasic')
    .controller('calendarController', function($scope, moment, calendarConfig, $http, Formio, shiftService, AppConfig, $q) {

    var vm = this;

    calendarConfig.templates.calendarMonthCell = 'views/calendar/dayTemplate.html';
    calendarConfig.dateFormatter = 'moment';

    vm.events = [];
    vm.calendarView = 'month';
    vm.viewDate = moment().startOf('month').toDate();
    vm.appConfig = AppConfig;
    vm.currentUser = Formio.getUser();
    // Get station config.
    var stationPromise = shiftService.getStationConfig().then(function(data) {
      vm.configSlots = data;
    });

    var onShifts = function(data) {
      vm.events = data;
    };

    var onError = function(error) {
      vm.error = 'There was an error.';
    };

    vm.addName = function(userId) {
      // Code to add name to back end.

    };

    vm.removeName = function(userId) {
      // Code to remove name from back end.
    };

    -- rest of controller code goes here

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      calendarConfig.templates.calendarMonthCell = 'mwl/calendarMonthCell.html';
    });
  });
})();
```

And here's the custom template for the calendar cell.

```
<div class="cal-month-day">

    <span
      class="pull-right"
      data-cal-date
      ng-click="calendarCtrl.dateClicked(day.date)"
      ng-bind="day.label">
    </span>

  <div ng-if="day.todayHasShifts">{{ day.text }}</div>

      <table ng-class="{ today: day.isToday }" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Station</td>
              <td>Position</td>
              <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="shift in day.shiftTables">
              <tr ng-repeat="slot in shift.slots">
                <td align="top" ng-attr-rowspan>{{ shift.station }}</td>
                <td>{{ slot.position }}</td>
                <td ng-if="slot.nameOption == 'printNameRemove'" class="print-name-remove"><a href="" ng-click="vm.removeName(slot.name)">{{ slot.name }}</a></td>
                <td ng-if="slot.nameOption == 'printName'" class="print-name">{{ slot.name }}</td>
                <td ng-if="slot.nameOption == 'printSignupLink'" class="print-signup-link"><a href="" ng-click="vm.addName(slot.name)">Sign Up</a></td>
                <td ng-if="slot.nameOption == 'printBlank'" class="print-blank"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

The problem I'm having is that clicking on the link is not triggering the addName and removeName functions in the controller. I'm sure I must be missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing what it is. What do I need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find any problem either. Which version of angular you're using? Can you try to replace the anchor with a button to see if it works?

Comment: I'm using 1.5.8. Using a button doesn't make any difference. Based on some stuff I'm seeing in the console, it looks like it's calling the whole controller again, instead of just the specific function.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce that in a fiddle?

Comment: I'll try a Plunker, but there's a decent amount of code and a separate back end that holds all the data, so it would be pretty hard to get it all in something like jsfiddle or plnkr.

Comment: @gyc, you can see the code in my GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/wonder95/formio-volunteers/blob/master/src/app/resources/shift/calendarController.js). The template that renders each day cell is [here](https://github.com/wonder95/formio-volunteers/blob/master/src/app/resources/shift/calendarController.js).